# Why does a single record lookup return an array? (Rails beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a **where** operation on a model that returns a single object. But I can't seem to use it in object notation (it appears to return an array with the object at [0]).

```
store = Store.where("some_id = ?", some_id)

puts store.name  # doesn't work

puts store  # shows array with the object at [0]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because sometimes you don't know how many objects a query should return, so for consistency you always get an array.

To get a single object use

```
store = Store.where("some_id = ?", some_id).first
```

If you are looking for the primary ID of the model, you can also use

```
store = Store.find(some_id)
```

which will raise a RecrodNotFound exception (handled by rails as a 404 by default) if it doesn't find the object.

Comment: how could I check if no results were returned? this doesn't seem to work: `puts store.name unless store.blank`

Comment: It will return `nil` if nothing was found, you can check with `store.nil?`.

Comment: One last silly question Jakub... Is there a better notation to write the `.where("some_id = ?", some_id)` ... does something like this work in rails... `.where(:some_id => some_id)`

Comment: Sure it does :) In fact those two should work the same. Also see my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There are also dynamic finders

```
Store.find_by_some_id(some_id)
```

They are equivalent to

```
Store.where(:some_id => some_id).first
```

Comment: Worth noting, dynamic finders (other than find_by*) are not supported in Rails 4

Source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

Answer (score 0):

Where clause in rails 3.x will always return and arel objec, which you can use for method chaining.

Thus return statement of the where clause is always an array.

For accessing the first element you have to do

`object.first`  as suggested by Jakub