# Rails - undefined method `authenticate'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, activerecord

I am receiving following error while trying to authenticate a user.

`NoMethodError (undefined method`authenticate' for #)`

user.authenticate('password') is successful(i.e returns the user object) when I execute the command from rails console.

```
irb(main):008:0> user.authenticate("sanket")
=> #<User id: 2, name: "Sanket", email: "sanket.meghani@infibeam.net", created_at: "2014-02-14 08:58:28", updated_at: "2014-02-14 08:58:28", password_digest: "$2a$10$KNuBgvqVDIErf3a24lMcaeNt1Hyg0I8oreIQSEYsXY4T...", remember_token: "3b64273a4fcced7c8bf91f7f7490e60a5919658d">
```

However when I put user.authenticate in a helper class, and access it using a url, it says

`undefined method 'authenticate' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fd9506dce38>`

I am following [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec-signin_upon_signup)

My user model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base        
    attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
    has_secure_password

    .
    .
    .
end
```

Related method in session_helper.rb looks like:

```
def create
    user = User.where(:email => params[:session][:email].downcase)

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render "new"
    end
end
```

It gives above error on `if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])` line.

What surprises me is, it is working from rails console, however the same call is not working from rails server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see in your error, `where` returns a relation, not a single object.

Check the related question: [Why does a single record lookup return an array? (Rails beginner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026095/why-does-a-single-record-lookup-return-an-array-rails-beginner)

In your case, you can add `first` to the end of method chain, so it will return the first element of this relation:

```
user = User.where(:email => params[:session][:email].downcase).first
```

Comment: That explains it. Thank you.